# How do I test extra parameters in Remix?

Tags: remix, payable, remix-tests

I tried to use **Remix** to test a Smart Contract:

```
/********************************************************************
* Make bids with ETH or an ERC20 Token specified by the NFT seller.*
* Additionally, a buyer can pay the asking price to conclude a sale*
* of an NFT.                                                      *
********************************************************************/

function makeBid(
    address _nftContractAddress,
    uint256 _tokenId,
    address _erc20Token,
    uint128 _tokenAmount
)
    external
    payable
    auctionOngoing(_nftContractAddress, _tokenId)
    onlyApplicableBuyer(_nftContractAddress, _tokenId)
{
    _makeBid(_nftContractAddress, _tokenId, _erc20Token, _tokenAmount);
}
```

This is my JavaScript test:

```
await nftAuction
    .connect(user2)
    .makeBid(erc721.address, tokenId, zeroAddress, zeroERC20Tokens, {
        value: minPrice,
    });
```

These are my parameters for the function `makeBid`:

```
"0xD4Fc541236927...",1,"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",0, {value:100,}
```

[image: remix]

The last one is an extra parameter, because the function is Payable and accept Ether transfers, it works well in Hardhat test, so I tried in Remix to input this line same as above and got this error from console `"code=INVALID_ARGUMENT"`.

What's the right syntax to try this on **Remix**?

Comment: Can you make a screenshot of your input in remix ?

Comment: @MajdTL I updated the question...of course, for privacy, I truncated the first address.

Comment: Okay don’t add the value inside the function input field. Remix provide above the „deploy button“ 2 input fields for how much you want to send and in which unit (Wei, gwei, ether)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to call payable function and send ether with the transaction in remix IDE, then you need to use those 2 provided input fields. The given amount is not related to the gas fees.
Your contract must check the sent amount of  ether with msg.value

[image: Send-ether]

Comment: Ok got it, so I keep 0 as value in my contract deployed and add a value in WEI or ETH etc. above at the top. Cool, thanks.

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean. Your contract MUST check the amount that has been sent with msg.value  @NineCattoRules

Comment: You just need to remove {value:100} from your input field

Comment: Yes, it is what I said.

Comment: Since it's a similar question, could you please help me again? https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/128741/11332