# Remix - Error: cannot encode object for signature with missing names

Tags: remix, arrays

I'm trying to pass this Array of JSON objects in **Remix**:

```
[{"nft": "0xd914...", "id": 0},{"nft": "0xd914...", "id": 1},{"nft": "0xd914...", "id": 2}]
```

However I get this error:

```
Error: cannot encode object for signature with missing names (argument="values", coder={"name":"address","type":"address","localName":null,"dynamic":false}, value={"nft":"0xd914...","id":0}, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=abi/5.5.0)
```

Here is the function:

```
function addAirdrops(Airdrop[] memory _airdrops) external {
    uint _nextAirdropId = nextAirdropId;
    for(uint i = 0; i < _airdrops.length; i++) {
      airdrops[_nextAirdropId] = _airdrops[i];
      IERC721(_airdrops[i].nft).transferFrom(
        msg.sender, 
        address(this), 
        _airdrops[i].id
      );
      _nextAirdropId++;
    }
  }
```

Am I missing something, or it's a Remix bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the following struct

```
struct Airdrop {
   bytes32 nft;
   uint256 id;
}
```

Then the input should looks like this:

`[[bytes32-of-nft, id], [...], [...]]`

example:

`[["0x3272323133313234323134323134313234000000000000000000000000000000", 2], ["0x3272323133313234323134323134313234000000000000000000000000000000", 3]]`

the bytes32 is 64 chars + extra `0x` = 66 CHARACTERS

Comment: by the way using arrays for Airdrop ist not good, and very expansive on ethereum mainnet. It is better to use merkle trees for airdrops.. there are many examples on how to airdrop ERC20 and with small change you can do it for nfts

Comment: Thanks! I was wrong because the test in Truffle is very different as you can see from the code here: https://github.com/jklepatch/eattheblocks/blob/master/screencast/394-nft-airdrop/test/NFTAirdrop.js